# php loop error with iframe

Tags: php, loops, iframe

How can I fix this script?
The result that I'm looking for is

```
The number is: 1 and  <iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
The number is: 2 and  <iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
The number is: 3 and  <iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
```

and i use this script

```
<?php  
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
  echo "The number is: $x and  <iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" height="200" width="300"></iframe> <br>";
}
?>  

</body>
</html>
```

But the result is an error.

Comment: look at your quotes

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When asking questions like this always *include the error you got*. It can be vital to diagnosing more complex problems. In this case though .. ya, fix your quotes. And consider using `printf()` instead of `echo`.

Answer (score 2):

```
   <?php  
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
      echo 'The number is: '.$x.' and  <iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" height="200" width="300"></iframe> <br>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: thx for the answer :D

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($x = 0; $x <=10; $x++) {

echo "The number is:".$x.' and <iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" height="200" width="300"></iframe> <br>';
 }
```

Comment: thx for the answer :D

Comment: welcome Fian Julio :)